# cifs/nfs server down , Client server high load average

Tags: nfs, cifs, load-average, rpcbind

I have an backup server in my AWS network. For maintenance i rebooted the server, after  which it is not starting.

My problem is all the servers were having backup server disk mounted through nfs (cifs) for storing the backups.
Now the load average of the client server is 50 and the cpu is idle. 
Please let me know, how to resolve the issue.

Thanks,
Raghu Reddy

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of two things:

1. Make the nfs server online again(preserve the original IP)
2. Find the mountpoint of nfs through `nfsstat -m`
   and umount the mountpoints through `umount -fl $MOUNTPOINT`

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring up a host with the same IP of the server which is not starting. If possible the host should have a nfs/cifs-server running.

As soon as the server can be reached you can do the unmount on the clients and the load will drop.

Could be that the load will drop even without umounting, but once you have to shutdown the temporary server (because you will bring up the real-server again) and without umounting, the load will increase again, till the real server is up and running.

**Reminder:** The load is not calculated from the cpu usage. The load shows the ready-to-run waiting (for resources) processes in the process scheduler. The waiting processes are usually in state "D".